# AVPlayerItem externalMetadata unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, crash, ios12, unrecognized-selector, avplayeritem

This piece of code is crashing on iOS 12 with unrecognised selector exception:

`[AVPlayerItem externalMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

However, this code is not crashing on iOS 13.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1627623-externalmetadata) states that AVPlayerItem has `externalMetadata` getter and setter since iOS 12.

```swift
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)

    let mutableMetadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    mutableMetadataItem.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifier.commonIdentifierDescription
    mutableMetadataItem.value = 1
    item.externalMetadata.append(mutableMetadataItem)
```

Could you please help me to understand why is that happening?

Comment: You should file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @matt just did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`externalMetadata` was introduced in iOS 13. That fact is explicitly called out in the relevant WWDC 2019 video. Simply put, the docs (or the availability tags) are wrong — and the result of the mistake is that you are permitted to use `externalMetadata` in a context (iOS 12) where it is actually absent, and so you crash.